# C++ 2D Array Ping Pong Board

Tags: c++, c, arrays, 2d

I can't find my mistake is my code. I'm trying to create a "board" and draw something on it with X and Y as coordinates. The problem is that the char I want to draw appears more than once. Here is the code:

```
class Board
{
public:

    void fillBoard()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 22; i++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < 78; k++)
            {
                board[i][k] = ' ';
            }
        }
    }

    void drawBoard()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 22; i++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < 78; k++)
            {
                cout<<board[i][k];
            }
            cout<<"\n";
        }
    }

    void addView(int width, int height, char img, int tallness = 0)
    {
        /// board[height][width] = img;
        for (int i = 0; i <= tallness; i++, height++)
        {
            board[height][width] = img;
        }
    }

private:
   char board[78][22];
};


int main()
{
    Board board;
    board.fillBoard();

    ///board.addView(x, y, 'O');
    board.addView(0, 10, '|', 5); 
    board.drawBoard();

    return 0;
}
```

So as you see, the paddle appears 4 times. I want it to appear only once, at the given coordinates. What is my mistake?

Comment: you're indexing backwards, as if you had declared the board [22][78]. this manifests as printing out a character twice, because you are doing that

Comment: Could you post what its currently printing out and what you want it to print out? I don't know what you mean by "paddle".

Comment: what does "addView" mean? Is a paddle one pipe ("|")?

Comment: @awesomeyi http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cc65ac65539ca56c

Comment: if you want it to appear only once, why do you pass `tallness = 5` to the for loop?

Comment: @RedAlert The char should appear 5 times vertically. Look at the link above

Comment: God... I've been looking for this sh*t for almost a hour... Thanks alot! :)

Comment: @Appleshell it loops 6 times for `tallness == 5` so this code should draw it 6 times vertically.

Comment: @MattMcNabb You're right, that's however irrelevant...

Answer (score 3):

Steve Cox already pointed out that you are indexing the array backwards. This:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 22; i++)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < 78; k++)
    {
        board[i][k] = ' ';
    }
}
```

Would work on a array `board[22][78]`, however you are declaring a `board[78][22]`

Comment: God... I've been looking for this sh*t for almost a hour... Thanks alot! :)